# jQuery addClass on click to specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to animate a menu item.
On move over it expands left, and on mouse out it contracts back.
This works fine.

I am also trying to add a class on click to give the button a specific color but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g3ra912j/

css:

```
    #menu1 .active {
        background-color: #00f;
    }
```

script:

```
$("#menu1").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active")
})
```

onclick it supposed to turn blue, but it doesn't.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space in your CSS. Should be

```
#menu1.active {
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

since you are adding the class .active to the same element as has the id menu1. The original CSS would target an element with class .active **inside** #menu1.

Comment: you can use  -- #menu1.active {background-color: #00f;} -- or  just this  -- .active {background-color: #00f;}

Comment: I have to wait 7 minutes before I can mark yours as the correct answer but I will soon. Thanks!!

Also, I am going to have 4 colors for the menu buttons. is my approach for giving each an individual color correct or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

i had to deal with the same problem. use addClass('active') instead toggleClass. just have an if condition to check if the element already has active class before adding active class

let me know if it works.

and about the css bobdye was right